# Where does my friend live? 6

Tags: riddle

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

My friend, a poet, sent me a poem:

> I live in a country,
> There are bridges and rivers and boats,
> on the axis.
> There was fighting over a roulette,
> tourists wandered throughout its capital.
> Askew was the roller pin,
> copy and paste on the tomato sauce.
> The circle constantly snoozes,
> pelicans on a city.

**Do you know where he is?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You are referring to Italy

I live in a country,

There are bridges and rivers and boats,

> A reference to Venice- a city that only uses boats as a means of transport...

on the axis.

> In WW2 Italy fought on the Axis' side.

There was fighting over a roulette, tourists wandered throughout its capital

> In the first half you are referring to Colosseum as Roullete means a 'wheel' and the shape of the Colosseum is circular. I also thought that it might have been Casino as Casino is a word of Italin origin but the Op said my first answer was correct. In the second part you are referring to Rome, sounds like roam (roam is a synonym of wander) which is also its capital.

Askew was the roller pin,

> The leaning tower of Pisa.

copy and paste on the tomato sauce.

> This is referring to Italian coffee and pasta, famous Italian cuisine.

The circle constantly snoozes,

> Op says this is referring to Pizza. Circle is a clue to Pi and snoozes to zz.

pelicans on a city.

> This is referring to Vatican city I am sure. The hint is that Pelican rhymes with Vatican.

Comment: A couple of the clues sort of fit with this but most of them don't, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please elaborate...

Comment: Oh, on my phone it has 9 lines..., Now I used auto rotate, I see 8 lines, I see where the confusion was.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino...the word is of Italian origin.

Comment: Did I get all the clues right?